# Fluentd read jetty log with multiple lines

Tags: log4j, jetty, config, fluentd

im trying to read multiple lines of a jetty log, for a source does anyone now how to do it?

```
<source>
type tail
format multiline
format_firstline /^\[/
format1 /^\[[^ ]* (?<time>[^\]]*)\] *(?<level>[^ ]*) $/
path /mnt/current/log/jettylog4j.log
pos_file /mnt/current/log/fluentd.jettylog4j.pos
read_from_head true
tag jettylog
refresh_interval 30
</source>
```

With this I don't manage to have the messages with all the lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I cannot change the format as is part of the legacy code. I found a pattern that works for me. I put it here in case is useful for someone

```
<source>
type tail
format multiline
format_firstline /^\[/
format1 /^\[[^ ]* (?<time>[^\]]*)\] *(?<level>[^ ]*) (?<message>[^\n]*(\n^[^\[].*|$))/
path /mnt/current/log/jettylog4j.log
pos_file /mnt/current/log/fluentd.jettylog4j.pos
read_from_head true
tag jettylog
refresh_interval 30
</source>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using log4j for your logging.

Its output format and syntax is controlled by its log4j configuration.

You might want to sync up your fluentd efforts with your log4j configuration, maybe even make some small adjustments on the log4j configuration side to make your life easier in fluentd.

Note, log4j can even be configured to output in xml or json or directly into your fluentd database, making the parsing step at least easier.

*Tip: if you decide to go this route, you'll want to know if you are using log4j 1.x or 2.x (as the documentation is different)*